# Change the value of X between each touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, touch

I am learning C #, help me, I am trying to pass the code that I use to make the keyboard sound but when I use the touch sometimes it stops detecting or increases the value and I already tried it on some devices and the same thing happens and I would like someone to tell me say how I could make it functional without that glitch.

This is the code I use on the PC

```
  private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
         {
             direccion = 5;
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
         {
 
             direccion = -5;
         }
         if (run2 == true)
         {
             gameObject.transform.Translate(direccion * Time.deltaTime, velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0);
         }
```

This is the code I am trying to use for phones.

```
 private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
         {
                 direct = true;
                 if (direct == true)
                 {
                     getTouch++;
                     direct = false; 
                 }
                 if (getTouch ==1)
                 {
                     direccion = 5;
                 }
                 else if (getTouch >= 2)
                 {
                     direccion = -5;
                     getTouch = 0;
                     direct = true;
                 }
             }
  
         if (run2 == true)
         {
             gameObject.transform.Translate(direccion * Time.deltaTime, velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0);
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after you set

```
direct = true;
```

the next

```
if(direct == true)
```

will always be the case.

In general instead of using a counter etc simply do e.g.

```
private int direction = 5;
```

and then later only alternate the sign doing

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
     direccion *= -1;
}
```

---

In general though:

You first code is ok since it uses **continous** input `GetKey` which is true every frame.

**But** whenever you use **single event** input like `GetKeyDown` or in your case the `TouchPhase.Began` which are `true` only within **one single frame** you should rather get your input in `Update`!

Since `FixedUpdate` might not be called every frame you might be tapping just within a frame where `FixedUpdate` is not called => you miss this touch input.

So rather use

```
private int direction = 5;

private void Update()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
             direccion *= -1;
        }
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
     if (run2)
     {
         transform.Translate(direccion * Time.deltaTime, velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, you are amazing, you reduced the code of the case completely.